# How to make use of rollapply or filter functions in R to create the moving average of a specific size in a 2D matrix

Tags: r, image-processing, matrix, filter, average

Considering that we have a padded matrix with window size k ready for getting smoothed using the moving average, I want to know if the `filter` or `rollapply` or other R functions I am not aware of can be used to find the moving average of a submatrix. Looking at R manuals I saw they have been used for MA in 1D but just wanted to know if they can be used for MA in 2D as well or not.

```
mat.pad<-function(X,k){
  dims<-dim(X)
  n<-dims[1]
  m<-dims[2]
  pad.X <- matrix(0, n + 2 * k, m + 2 * k)
  pad.X[(k + 1):(n + k), (k + 1):(m + k)] <- X
  return(pad.X)
}
```

Comment: Would you mind to provide an example of your data and the desired output?

Comment: See the `by.column` argument of `rollapply`.

Comment: I wrote this in another post

Answer (score 2):

If you are asking if a moving average can be applied to a multiple dimensional object, the answer is yes.

Example

```
library(zoo)
#
a <- 1:10
b <- 11:20
c <- cbind(a,b)
#
rollapply(c,
          FUN = mean,
          width = 3)
```